# blackberry webworks HTML5 Database path

Tags: database, html, blackberry-webworks

on the blackberry webworks API reference for HTML5 Database

it says:
Note: A SD card is the required method of storage for databases for 5.x devices

and to create a database:

```
db = window.openDatabase('documents', '1.0', 'Offline document storage', 5*1024*1024);
```

please how do i know where this database is created on the device? the path to the database?

And lastly how do i ensure the database is created on the SD card?

I am developing an app for BB 5+

Please assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On BlackBerry 5.0, the underlying technology used by WebDB is SQLite, which is only compatible with the SDCard flash memory.

When an SDCard is inserted in a BlackBerry, and as long as you don't have mass storage mode enabled (which temporarily disables access to the SDCard), then your app will automatically choose to save to the SDCard.

Here's a code example of using WebDB on BlackBerry:
http://blackberry.github.io/WebWorks-Samples/kitchenSink/html/html5/db.html